# apps.groups.migration 'success'ful failure

Tags: google-admin-sdk

So, I'm experimenting with apps.groups.migration, and I took my mbox and successfully inserted it into a test group.  Then I took another mbox from a list archive, and inserted that.  I got nothing but SUCCESS returns, but nothing ever appeared in the group.  Is there an age limit?  Some of these notes are years old, but we're trying to migrate from our existing listserv to groups, and would like to bring the archives.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the messages in the list archive had had their message-id's stripped out.  This causes the message to not be posted to the archive, but still returns a "SUCCESS" result.